# Wordpress Excerpt Character Limit On Theme wpexplorer Today Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need help for fixing http://wpexplorer-demos.com/today/page/2/ today theme.

frontpage Boxes takes random sizes. How i fix it from words to characters. Also images. any help plz really appreciated. I am not a coder.

```
/**
 * Custom excerpts based on wp_trim_words
 * Created for child-theming purposes
 * 
 * @link  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function wpex_excerpt( $length = 45, $readmore = false ) {

    // Get global post data
    global $post;

    // Check for custom excerpt
    if ( has_excerpt( $post->ID ) ) {
        $output = $post->post_excerpt;
    }

    // No custom excerpt...so lets generate one
    else {

        // Redmore text
        $readmore_text = get_theme_mod( 'entry_readmore_text', esc_html__( 'read more', 'today' ) );

        // Readmore link
        $readmore_link = '<a href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) .'" title="'. $readmore_text .'">'. $readmore_text .'<span class="wpex-readmore-rarr">&rarr;</span></a>';

        // Check for more tag and return content if it exists
        if ( strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--more-->' ) ) {
            $output = get_the_content( '' );
        }

        // No more tag defined so generate excerpt using wp_trim_words
        else {

            // Generate excerpt
            $output = wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes( get_the_content( $post->ID ) ), $length );

            // Add readmore to excerpt if enabled
            if ( $readmore == true ) {
                $output .= apply_filters( 'wpex_readmore_link', $readmore_link );
            }

        }

    }

    // Apply filters and echo
    echo apply_filters( 'wpex_excerpt', $output );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited it for you:

```
**
 * Custom excerpts based on wp_trim_words
 * Created for child-theming purposes
 * 
 * @link  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function wpex_excerpt( $length = 45, $readmore = false ) {

    // Get global post data
    global $post;

   $max_characters = 40;

    // Check for custom excerpt
    if ( has_excerpt( $post->ID ) ) {
        $output = mb_strimwidth($post->post_excerpt, 0, $max_characters, '...');
    }

    // No custom excerpt...so lets generate one
    else {

        // Redmore text
        $readmore_text = get_theme_mod( 'entry_readmore_text', esc_html__( 'read more', 'today' ) );

        // Readmore link
        $readmore_link = '<a href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) .'" title="'. $readmore_text .'">'. $readmore_text .'<span class="wpex-readmore-rarr">&rarr;</span></a>';

        // Check for more tag and return content if it exists
        if ( strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--more-->' ) ) {
  $output = mb_strimwidth(get_the_content( '' ), 0, $max_characters, '...');
        }

        // No more tag defined so generate excerpt using wp_trim_words
        else {

            // Generate excerpt
            $output_to_trim = wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes( get_the_content( $post->ID ) ), $length );
$output = mb_strimwidth($output_to_trim, 0, $max_characters, '...');    
            // Add readmore to excerpt if enabled
            if ( $readmore == true ) {
                $output .= apply_filters( 'wpex_readmore_link', $readmore_link );
            }

        }

    }

    // Apply filters and echo
    echo apply_filters( 'wpex_excerpt', $output );

}
```

You can change the maximum of characters in this code by changing number in *$max_characters* variable.

I used *mb_strimwidth()* function and return it to *$output* variable: https://secure.php.net/manual/pl/function.mb-strimwidth.php

By example you should understand what's going on:

```
 <?php
echo mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...");
// outputs Hello W...
?>
```

The function needs string like "Hello World", start of string (like 0), maximum number of characters (like 10) and at the end you can optionally choose nice ending of excerpt (like ...).